# Implementing azure SSO with SPA

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I am working on a SPA with node on back-end. I looked into couple of examples and libraries but having trouble implementing azure SAML SSO? I am using JWT token based authentication for my react front-end.

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Comment: I already had the SPA application and node back-end with JWT authentication. I need to add azure ad SSO in current application. I used server to server openid authentication. But now i need to implement SAML based SSO authentication. I looked into few libraries MSAL, Azure ad node but still having trouble...